# Trying to get this Django template code to print a newline *before* each h4 heading

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I've re-done this code. If I'm understanding this template code correctly, it looks like I had some CSS in an unnecessary place (within the h3 tags, which isn't necessary). Regardless, I still need to code in the same behavior that I wrote about in my earlier post. Now that I only have one loop (well, technically two) I think this might be a little easier

Create another loop to do this or is there an easier way?

Here's the code, re-done: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/300897/

Thanks,
J.

- Note: here is the CSS code for product-category class:
  ul.product-category li {float: left; display: inline-block;}

Comment: Here is my CSS ul.product-category li {float: left; display: inline-block;} Not sure how I'd tell the CSS when h4 print newline. I really don't know CSS so any suggestions would be welcomed. My first initial guess would be something with width or margins? I've also re-done the code, some of it was unnecessary. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is *specifically removing* the newline for the H4, which normally does automatically go on a line by itself. Remove that CSS definition completely and it will go on a new line all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved the the problem I was having. What I did was add div in the template code like this: `<div class="clear_both"></div>` right before the h4 heading that calls a clear:both CSS property, which sort of acts as a newline. Now I can add as many items as I'd like and they will continue to wrap around until another h4 heading is created.